# How can I speedup node.js File operations?

Tags: performance, node.js, express, download, mongoose

In my project, a client will request to download a file from server with an id. I have to perform the following operations:

- Validate the id from mongoDb
- Check extension
- Check File exists or not
- Read the file and write content to response

I am using the following code for checking file and sending the response.

```
fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    res.writeHead(404, '', {
      "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
    })
    res.write("404 Not Found\n");
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500, '', {
        "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
      })
      res.write(err + "\n");
      res.end();
      return;
    }
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600");
    res.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding:  chunked");
    res.setHeader("Range:  chunked");
    res.writeHead(200, '', {
      "Content-Type" : contentType
    });
    res.write(file, "binary");
    res.end(file, "binary");
  });
});
```

Within a few milliseconds, the client will request hundreds of files. The supporting file types are image,audio or video.

When there are lots of files in the folder, node.js is taking too much time to download the file. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: maybe you can zip them and send as single file?

Comment: @Dream707: No I can't zip the files.I have to serve them individually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend a few things.

1. You should not be using `'binary'`. Don't give an encoding at all. By adding the encoding, you are making node do a ton of extra work to convert the file's `Buffer` object into a binary-encoded `string`. When you call `write` again with `'binary'` that means node has to then do that same operation in reverse. Also you are passing the file to both `end` and `write`, meaning every file you download will contain the file data twice.
2. I'd recommend against using `readFile`. Since `readFile` passes the whole file contents back to you in your `file` variable, you are requiring node to load the whole contents of the file into RAM, meaning it needs to allocate a ton of buffers and then concatenate them, which is unneeded work.
3. There is no reason to use `exists` separately, because if you try to open a file that does not exist, the error will tell you, so checking first is just extra work.

Also, the `Transfer-encoding` header will be set all by itself, you don't need to do it.

Something like this should be faster:

```
fs.createReadStream(filename)
    .on('error', function(err){
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT'){
            res.writeHead(404, {
                'Content-type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.end('404 Not Found\n');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(500, {
                'Content-type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.end(err + '\n');
        }
    })
    .on('open', function(){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Pragma': 'public',
            'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=3600',
            'Content-type': contentType
        });
    })
    .pipe(res);
```

Comment: @loganfsmyth if using `express`, how about just `sendFile()` (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) ?